# How to resolve undefined google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP issue when implementing Google Maps in Ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to display google maps in my ionic app.

The map is displaying, but when I try to add this `mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP` to my mapOptions below:

```
loadMap() {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.9036442, 7.6673267);

    let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 5,
        // mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
}
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROADMAP' of undefined
>       at HomePage.loadMap

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: try mapTypeId:'roadmap'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

> mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP

to

> mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

notice the different, hope this helps. Cheers